# How to plot 3d networks plots labels

Tags: r, networking, graph

I am trying to plot a 3D network graph using the following code.

```
rm(list = ls(all=TRUE))    
graphics.off()
library(readxl)
library(igraph)
library(threejs)

NTWVD <- read_excel("C:/Users/Mihan/Dropbox/DataCamp/R/Network_Analysis/NTWVD.xlsx")
NT.mat<-as.matrix(NTWVD)
NT1.mat<-NT.mat[,1:2]

g<-graph.edgelist(NT1.mat, directed=FALSE)

g<-set_vertex_attr(g, "color", value=c("red","blue","green","red","green","red","green","green","green","green","green","yellow","yellow","yellow","yellow","yellow","blue","yellow","red","black","black","black","black","black","black","red","red","blue","blue","blue","blue"))

graphjs(g,vertex.size = 1, showLabels=TRUE)

graphjs(g, main = "", curvature = 0, bg = "white",
        fg = "black", showLabels = TRUE, attraction = 1, repulsion = 1,
        max_iterations = 1500, opacity = 1, stroke = TRUE, width = NULL,
        height = NULL)
```

I have a beautiful interactive plot. But I do not see any labels over the vertexes. I have two columns in this data. Vertex 1 and Vertex 2.
Please advise how can I show labels over the vertices in the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I found a solution [here](https://bwlewis.github.io/rthreejs/adding_points.html) and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/threejs/versions/0.3.1/topics/points3d). I understood that in your case the solution would be:

```
graphjs(g, main = "", curvature = 0, bg = "white",
        fg = "black", showLabels = TRUE, attraction = 1, repulsion = 1,
        max_iterations = 1500, opacity = 1, stroke = TRUE, width = NULL,
        height = NULL)%>%points3d(vertices(.), color="red",pch=V(g)$label,size=0.1)
```

Comment: thank you so much. The 3d Network was built successfully.